# Authenticator in Kerberos

Tags: security, kerberos, kerberos-delegation

When we try to connect to the Ticket granting server we have to create the authenticator and also send the service to which we are trying to connect.
My question is do we manually create the authenticator and type in the service or is it an automated process(when we log in the machine will only connect to that service only )

Comment: This question might find better reception on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Example:

A User needs to login using  *kinit username/username*  to access a service at a particular host. It will ask for your password and if the credentials are matched, you will get access to the service. This is perspective from user side.

But from Admin side, He/she needs to generate keytab files for both hosts and services and copy it to the host where services are present.Also, all the users accessing the system should be generated in KDC database.We can also pull users from Active directory.

For more info: http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/krb5-1.13/doc/admin/install_kdc.html

Comment: Okay.. So if i have a kerberos realm with many services, is it pre defined by the administrator  what service can I access or I will have to send a message to the TGS requesting the service manually.

Comment: You cannot request for a particular service. All the principals for the services are generated by the administrator.